# TikZ - How to refer and redraw a layer previously draw

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a figure made up of a square on Layer 1, then four disks on top making Layer 2, and then a blue letter on top making Layer 3. As in:

[image]

How can I refer to a "subtraction of Layer 1 - Layer 2" that is the interstitial space that belongs to the square but not the disks - and redraw it on top as Layer 4, so parts of the letter will be gone and only the parts that are on top of the disks will be visible.

The code for the current figure is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

%Layer 1:
 \shade (0,0) rectangle (4,4);

%Layer 2:
 \shade (1,1) circle [radius=1];
 \shade (3,1) circle [radius=1];
 \shade (1,3) circle [radius=1];
 \shade (3,3) circle [radius=1];

%Layer 3:
 \node [shift={(1.0cm, 5.5cm)}, anchor=north west,rotate=20] (A) {
       \textcolor{blue}{\fontsize{180pt}{11pt}\selectfont{\textbf{A}}}
 };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `clip` operation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

  % Layer 1:
  \shade (0,0) rectangle (4,4);

  % Layer 2:
  \shade (1,1) circle [radius=1];
  \shade (3,1) circle [radius=1];
  \shade (1,3) circle [radius=1];
  \shade (3,3) circle [radius=1];

  % Clip
  \clip 
  (1,1) circle [radius=1]
  (3,1) circle [radius=1]
  (1,3) circle [radius=1]
  (3,3) circle [radius=1];

  % Layer 3:
  \node [shift={(1.0cm, 5.5cm)}, anchor=north west,rotate=20,
  color=blue,font=\fontsize{180pt}{180pt}\selectfont]
  (A) {\textbf{A}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]